# If you are really good at Python and Regex, please help fix function

Tags: python, regex

```
def boldword(text, needle):
    return mark_safe(re.compile(r"\b(%s)\b" % "|".join(map(re.escape, needle.split(' '))), re.I).sub(r'<strong>\1</strong>', text))
```

This is currently my function to bold a string text given a needle. (Like Google...they bold the text for you when you do a search).

- When the needle is "the show", it will not highlight  "www.**theshow**.com".
- When the needle is "my show (video)", it will not highlight "**my show (video)**"...it only highlights **my show**.
- When the needle is "apple's ipad", it will not highlight "apple ipad"...it only highlights ipad.

  Expected output:
      www.**theshow**.com
  ,Current output:
      www.theshow.com

  Expected output:
      **my show (video)**
  ,Current output:
      **my show** (video)

  Expected:
      **apple ipad**
  ,Current:
      apple **ipad**

I think the main problem is when I'm splitting the space vs other punctuation. right?
Can someone modify my current function to take into account those factors?

Thanks

Comment: I think you should be writing in Lisp!

Comment: Are the output examples you gave your expected output or your observed output? If it is your observed output, what is your expected output?

Comment: The examples are my expected output. I"ll edit to make clear.

Comment: So it should be able to combine words? What about non-consecutive words? E.g.: boldword('a b c', 'ac')... should 'ac' be in bold or not?

Comment: I think you need to give either a better explanation of what you want, or a lot more than 3 reference examples.

Answer (score 2):

Your biggest problem seems to be the word boundaries.  If the tokens you're searching for can begin or end with non-word characters (e.g., `(video)`), enclosing the regex in `\b` prevents matching.  They also prevent matching of two or more contiguous tokens (e.g., `theshow` in `www.theshow.com`).  However, instead of losing the word boundaries, I suggest you ignore punctuation characters in the search expression and construct the regex so as to match one or more tokens at a time:

```
re.compile(r"\b((?:%s)+)\b" % "|".join(re.split(r"\W+", needle)), re.I)
```

Splitting on `/\W+/` removes all punctuation as well as whitespace, so there's no need to escape anything.  My results seem to match the ones you wanted, except the parentheses in `(video)` are not highlighted, only the word `video` is.  If the search expression is `"the show"`, it highlights `theshow` in `www.theshow.com`, but not in `www.footheshowbar.com`.

Answer (score 1):

What your description told me is that A) The input variable isn't being correctly split by spaces and B) It's not being properly escaped.

I think it may be an instance of under parenthesized expressions:

Try this:

```
return mark_safe(re.compile((r"\b(%s)\b" % ("|".join(map(re.escape, needle.split(' '))), re.I))).sub(r'<strong>\1</strong>', text))
```

Comment: Recommending more parenthesis is cruel.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some duct tape I added to help you pass the cases you listed -- this problem is actually pretty interesting.  There are probably some cases that won't be correct (e.g. Google will highlight `duck` if you search for `ducks`, this will only work for `duck's`).

Without a more general set of guidelines, it is tough to write a regex that will cover every case - but depending on how close you need it to be will ultimately decide on how complex you will need to make it.

```
import re, string

def boldword(text,needle):
    n = re.sub('[%s]s*' % re.escape(string.punctuation), '', needle)
    patterns = map(re.escape, n.split(' '))
    patterns.append(n.replace(' ', ''))
    regex = re.compile(r"\b(%s)\b" % '|'.join(patterns), re.I)
    match = re.match(regex, text.replace(' ',''))
    if match:
        return "<strong>%s</strong>" % text
    return re.sub(regex, r'<strong>\1</strong>', text)

print boldword("www.theshow.com", "the show")
print boldword("my show (video)", "my show (video)")
print boldword("apple ipad", "apple's ipad")
print boldword("stack overflow", "stackoverflow")
```

Output

```
>> www.<strong>theshow</strong>.com
>> <strong>my</strong> <strong>show</strong> (<strong>video</strong>)
>> <strong>apple ipad</strong>
>> <strong>stack overflow</strong>
```